# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Tags: three.js, gltf

I am trying to load a workshop (glTF file) in my scene but all I get is the error message

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined at GLTFLoader.js:2572

I tried opening the file in `Three.js` editor and in glTF Viewer and it worked, I also checked the file with glTF Validator and it said the file was valid but I can't figure out why it doesn't with me. I also tried to open another glTF model found on the Internet with my code and it worked just fine.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    const gltfloader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(manager);
    gltfloader.setCrossOrigin('anonymous');
    gltfloader.setDRACOLoader(new THREE.DRACOLoader());
    gltfloader.load("data/gltf/salleTP/salleTP.gltf", function (gltf) {
        const content = gltf.scene || gltf.scenes[0];
        scene.add(content);
    }, undefined, reject);
});
```

Comment: Open the chrome debugger.. put a breakpoint on the 'content = gltf.scene' line.. reload the app.. when the breakpoint hits, hover the mouse over 'gltf' and inspect the value.. proceed from there?

Comment: From what you describe it seems that the promise was not fulfilled yet and you try to use something which is defined when the promise is fulfilled. Is my hypothesis correct?

Comment: It does nothing because the error occurs on the gltfloader.load function. If I put a breakpoint on the load I don't have the error, but if I continue the error occurs and I can't see the content.

Comment: When I pause on the exception I can see that the 'geometry' value is undefined but 'geometries' is not empty and contains a BufferGeometry ! Is it possible that the file has multiple geometries and that is the reason it can't load ?

Comment: If you say that the file loads fine in the `three.js` editor it's obviously a problem in your app. Please demonstrate your issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/) or share your repo. This is the best way to help. Everything else is guesswork by the community.

Comment: @Mugen87 You can clone the repository from here : https://gitlab.com/gweil/virtual_workshop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using `three.js R102` and the respective `GLTFLoader` version. When loading your `glTF` asset, a known error in `GLTFLoader` occurs that was fixed with `R103` (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15881). After upgrading your code base to the latest `three.js` version, your asset loads fine.

[image]

`three.js R104`